# problem building uhd from source so that i can use in python

Tags: python, c++, boost, uhd

Boost library is not working and I am having an issue while building uhd libray for python using cmake.

I used these 2 commands for building the uhd library for python cloned from

```
git clone https://github.com/ettusresearch/uhd.git
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"
```

..

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

The error i am having is:
cmake --build . --config Release
MSBuild version 17.8.3+195e7f5a3 for .NET Framework

```
  1>Checking Build System
  uhd_rpclib.vcxproj -> D:\University\FYP\software\USRP\uhd\host\build\lib\deps\rpclib\uhd_rpclib.dir\Release\uhd_rpcli
  b.lib
  uhd-resources.vcxproj -> D:\University\FYP\software\USRP\uhd\host\build\lib\rc\Release\uhd-resources.lib
  build_info.cpp
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.lib' [D:\University\FYP\software\US
RP\uhd\host\build\lib\uhd.vcxproj]
```

Comment: Do you _have_ a file with that exact filename? What output did the first cmake call produce about Boost? We need that information to help you.